# Derivative of a function with two variables

Tags: calculus

I've been trying to solve this question

**Given that $f(x,y) = x\sin y + e^x \cos y,\ x = t^2 + 1$ & $y = t^2$ find the values of $\frac{df}{dt}$ at $t = 0$**

I tried putting in the values of $x\ \&\ y$ into the equation of $f(x,y)$ and solving directly but got confused along the way.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You need to use the chain rule

Comment: Ye, i thought about that. Can you give a detailed explanation?

Comment: $\frac{df}{dt}=\frac{df}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{df}{dy}\frac{dy}{dt}$

Comment: Is $\frac{df}{dx}$ the partial derivative of x?

Comment: Thanks finally got it. More info: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/ChainRule.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The notation does not make it explicit that $x$ and $y$ are functions of $t$. It might be helpful to write the various functions explicitly in the following way:
\begin{align*}
x(t) & = t^2 + 1 \\
y(t) & = t^2 \\
f(a, b) & = a \sin b + e^a \cos b.
\end{align*}
The question asks you to compute the derivative of the function $g$ defined by
$$
g(t) = f(x(t), y(t)).
$$
This is an application of the chain rule, which tells you
$$
g^\prime(t) = x^\prime(t) \frac{\partial f}{\partial a}(x(t), y(t)) + y^\prime(t) \frac{\partial f}{\partial b}(x(t), y(t)).
$$